# Extract first character of word to create acronym

Tags: java

How do i use split or stringtokenizer to get only the 1st character of each word to create an acronym? It would also include the '&' symbol. And it isn't case sensitive

exmaple:

- Some Kind Of Long String ---> SKOLS
- another Kind of Long String ---> AKOLS
- string & string ---> s&s

The reason for this is because i have a query that populates a table, and since the column name are 3 or more words each. it stretches the table, even with a scroll bar placed, 100+ columns with long names would make it look really long. So i would like to reduce space by using only acronyms and generating a legend.

Comment: The way this site works is that you post your code and we help you get it right.

Comment: I didn't really know if it mattered since this code isn't related to any important processes. I just wondered if i could shorten out the column names queried from the database since 100 or so column would mean a lot of scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to split the `String` at either " " or "&".

You can use the "split" method for String. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

The regular expression would be either space or ampersand.
Then you would use the `charAt` method to get the character at index 0. You would concatenate the characters to get the acronym.

Comment: Yes i was able to breakdown the string using split with " " as the delimiter. I just didnt know how to only get the first character of each string array. thanks for that